# Cant found Google Api AndroidPublisher Library

Tags: java, android, google-api

I can't find the AndroidPublisher library with the [AndroidPublisher Class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/AndroidPublisher.html).

Where can I find this class ? is it outdated now?

Comment: format and details